# Git reset changes from unstaged file

Tags: git

I'm new in git and I'm wondering if it is possible to reset changed to unstaged file? For example.

1. `echo 1 > file1.txt`
2. `git add file1.txt`
3. `git commit -m "file1 added to repo"`
4. `echo 2 > file1.txt`
5. `git add file1.txt`
6. `echo 3 > file1.txt`

State of my repo looks like this now:

1. In repo I've got file with content `1`
2. In stage I've got file with content `2`
3. In working dir I've got file with content `3`

How to reset file to point 2 (reset changes made by command `echo 3 > file2.txt`)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Are you wanting file1.txt to *not* be added now?

Comment: For 5, I think you mean `git add file2.txt`?

Comment: It was my mistake. I work only on one file `file1.txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I needed to use `git checkout -- file1.txt`. I didn't saw git help (use "git checkout -- ..." to discard changes in working directory) because primarily my file wasn't yet in repo. After I added file to repo git shows mi this tip.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
git clean -n
```

to check what files will be deleted and then

```
git clean -f
```

to delete untracked files

Answer (score 1):

Per the notes that git gives you, you'd do:

`git reset HEAD file1.txt`

This will move `file1.txt` out of tracked to untracked files.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
git checkout file2.txt
```

will reset your changes for unstaged file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unstage file1.txt:

```
git reset file1.txt
```

If you want to unstage everything (which is the same in this case):

```
git reset
```